# Графы. зашла в тупик, почти решив задачу

Tags: математика, графы

решала такую задачу на графы:

> В стране 77 городов, некоторые из которых соединены дорогами. При этом из любого города до любого существует путь, в котором ни один город не повторяется, а количество пройденных дорог делится на три. Какое минимальное количество дорог может быть в стране?

Мои рассуждения:

```
Нарисуем схему в виде графа, в котором города-это вершины, а дороги-ребра.
Так как получившийся граф связен(что видно из условия, ведь 
"...При этом из любого города до любого существует путь..."), то в нем 
заведомо минимум 76 ребер(доказывается по индукции, то есть с компонентой связности
из двух вершин должна соединяться третья, они образуют новую компоненту,
далее с ней должна быть соединена четвертая вершина и т.д.). 
Если вершин 76, то 2 вершины имеют степень 1, назовем их А и В. Но тогда
есть один, как вариант добраться до соседней с А вершиной, причем он состоит из 
1 ребра, нам такое не подходит. Аналогично опровергается возможность существования 77 ребер,
только здесь мы берем единственную вершину со степенью 1.
```

Но теперь я зашла в тупик, я не знаю, существует ли пример на 78 вершин, или есть опровержение... Думаю, если примера на 78 ребер нет, то на 79 ребер он существует точно...
Помогите пожалуйста!!! Заранее спасибо за помощь:)

Comment: Я догадываюсь, что раз количество дорог от любого до любого может делиться на 3, каджый город должен соединяться котя бы с 3 другими, отсюда и делитель 3. Но это не точно.

Comment: Не спрашивайте как я посчитал, но я предполагаю, что ответ **152** =) Я просто методом тыка соединял вершины в разных количествах и пытался найти закономерности =) Итого моя формула выглядит так: `3 + (x-3)*2 + xmod2`, где x - кол-во городов (вершин)

Answer (score 3):

Вы уже доказали что дерево не годится. Дерево - минимальный по числу рёбер связный граф.

Рассмотрите связный граф из 77 рёбер в котором нет вершин степени один (листьев). Докажите что любой такой граф - цикл. Покажите что цикл из 77 рёбер не подходит.

Рассмотрите граф из 78 рёбер в котором два цикла, которые имеют единственное общее ребро. Подберите длины циклов так чтобы из любой вершины в любую можно было добраться по пути с длиной кратной три.

Так как вы доказали что графы с числом рёбер менее 78 не подходят и привели пример для 78 рёбер - задача решена полностью.

Comment: почему решена? А если нельзя подобрать длины циклов так чтобы из любой вершины в любую можно было добраться по пути с длиной кратной три, учитывая, что в пути вершины не могут повторяться

Comment: @Grundy, я подобрал. Два цикла означают, что из любой вершины в любую есть три разных пути. Длины циклов подбираются так чтобы эти пути имели разные остатки по модулю три.

Comment: но ведь остаток должен быть 0?

Comment: @Grundy,  три пути - три разных остатка. Один должен быть нулём.

Comment: @Grundy, один цикл - 4, второй - 74. Можно показать что для любой пары вершин на большом цикле есть путь длиной кратной трём (пути - по часовой, против часовой, с заходом в петельку).

Comment: А почему три пути гарантируют три остатка?

Comment: @Grundy, не гарантируют, конечно. Отдельно нужно проверять что остатки разные, или просто для каждой пары предъявить путь.. Если выбрать неудачные размеры циклов, вроде 6 и 72, не всегда будет можно построить нужный путь.

Comment: то есть только подбором?

Comment: @Grundy, каждый цикл должен быть не кратен тройке. Циклы должны давать различные остатки при делении три. Этого достаточно, чтобы доказать что три пути дадут три различных остатка. Не совсем подбор.

Comment: То есть граф для 78 ребер выглядит следующим образом:

Comment: это 2 цикла, соединенные всего 1 ребром, причем каждый цикл не кратен 3, но чтобы подобрать подходящий пример все же придется перебрать много вариантов...